# Sequelize - Writing model types with .d.ts - everything is optional?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, typescript-typings, typescript-declarations

I'm trying to use `.d.ts` files to write type definitions for sequelize models in my JS. I have most of it working, however, all the properties are showing as optional in `Model.create()`.

`index.d.ts`:

```js
interface MyModelSchema extends Model<InferAttributes<MyModelSchema>, InferCreationAttributes<MyModelSchema>> {
  id: CreationOptional<string>;
  some_required_property: number;
  some_optional_property?: number;
}

type MyModel = ModelStatic<MyModelSchema>;
declare const MyModel: MyModel;
```

`index.js`: (MyModel is showing the correct type)

```js
// Properties on document are correctly marked as required
const document = MyModel.create({
  // All properties are optional here
});
```

Comment: That's completely normal. You might consider switching to something like TypeORM if possible (more TypeScript-oriented).

Comment: @kelly are you sure? The Sequelize TypeScript docs show information on how to make things required/optional for creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that all along I was just missing `"strictNullChecks": true,` in my `jsconfig.json`.